# How to call stored procedure on Teradata with SSIS sql execution task?

Tags: ssis, odbc, teradata, etl

I have a problem with calling a stored procedure with parameter on Teradata. I use SSDT 2015 and Teradata 15.10.1.10. The stored procedure has one parameter: `in VALID_FROM varchar(10)`

To escape date-conversion problems I choose to make input variable with type varchar and then inside the stored procedure I make conversion `cast(VALID_FROM as date)` and use it in queries.

So, I have two blocks is SSIS:
1) "GetInputParameter" (SQL execution task) that returns string with date.
2) "ExecuteProcedureOnDest" (SQL execution task) that calling stored procedure on Teradata through ODBC driver.

I checked that input parameter is a string with format 'YYYY-MM-DD', so it seems to me, that everything is ok. But when I run the package, I see an error on task "ExecuteProcedureOnDest":

> [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database]
>   SPINTORGLISTPREPARE:Invalid date.

I will be very grateful for help in solving this problem!

Comment: How are you casting that to a date in your proc, and then how are you using that cast?

Comment: I have tried two variants:
1) Declare date-variable in the stored procedure and made it equal to cast(VALID_FROM as date). And then I use only date-variable.
2) Simply use cast(VALID_FROM as date) in queries.

Comment: I think we'll need to see some code here. It sounds like perhaps the problem is that 'VALID_FROM` isn't a date type? Or something else is mismatched here.

Comment: I have understood what is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. The task "GetInputParameter" gives me a string '1900-01-01' (with quotes), but when I give it to the task "ExecuteProcedureOnDest" as SQLStatement = `call My.spIntOrgListPrepare(?)`, it goes without quotes there as 1900-01-01. And Teradata gives an error `Invalid date`.